# Is there a type accelerator for validating File- and Pathnames?

Tags: validation, powershell

I know there is a handy way to validate IPAdresses in Powershell:

`[ipaddress]"12.12.12.12"`

[ipaddress]"12.12.12.812" #Throws an Error.

Do you know if there is a similar way to validate File- and Pathnames?
e.g

`[path]"c:\temp\t?est.txt" #Throws an Error`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Test-Path` cmdlet:

```
Test-Path "c:\temp\t?est.txt" -IsValid
```

From help:

```
PS> help test-path -param isvalid

-IsValid [<SwitchParameter>]
    Determines whether the syntax of the path is correct, regardless of whether the elements of the path exist. This
    parameter returns TRUE if the path syntax is valid and FALSE if it is not.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                False
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Comment: Looking at that description it appears that's not going to tell you whether that file or path actually exists.  It's just doing a syntax check on the argument. - edit never mind.  That's exactly what's being ask for.  Duh.

Comment: true, but ipaddress does the same, it doesn't tell you if the ip exits, it just validates it. We can issue a second call to verify its existence, or vice versa in case I didn't under the OP.

Comment: Yes, i just wanted to validate a Parameter:
[ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -IsValid})]
 [string]$logfilepath
works for me. Thank you Shay!

Comment: Just kept googling around, found a Script with: 
[Parameter()] [System.IO.FileInfo]$OutputFile

Think this would be the same Testpath? Any pros or cons?

Comment: It's not the same, on my system there's no x drive and [System.IO.FileInfo]"x:\foo", works. test-path x:\foo.txt -IsValid returns false.